# Package xkeyval Error: `sort' undefined in families `blx@opt@pre'

Tags: xkeyval

Due to reasons unknown to me, I get the error described in the title. I do not know what the xkeyval package is, nor where I am using it. The error arose when I switched from bibtex to biblatex. My document is too big to include entirely, but I believe the relevant code is the following.

in the preamble:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[
  hyperref=auto,
  mincrossrefs=999,
  backend=biber,
  style=alphabetic,
  sort=nyt
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{allpapers.bib}
```

and then later in the actual document, I use

```
\printbibliography[title=\bibname]
```

I am very aware that this is not a super specific question. Sorry for this. I would be more specific if I knew more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is saying `sort=nyt` is an unknown option

https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=nyt

suggests that the option should be `sorting=nyt`

Comment: Thank you very much!